# Setting non-collapsed dependencies on Stanford Parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford Parser Java API in order to perform syntactic analysis, and I want to choose "non-collapsed dependencies that do not preserve a tree structure" mode.
In the manual, it says how this can be done using a console, but not using Java code.
Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Tree parseTree;
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parseTree);
Collection tdl = gs.typedDependencies();
```